# JDBC/JDBCTemplate Batch Operation

Tags: sql, jdbc, batch-processing, jdbctemplate

There are many examples out there with batch insert query using JDBC or JDBCTemplate.

I would like to do a batch sql operation comprises of Select, Insert and Delete. For instance, I need to issue following sql operation in single connection to database.

1. Multiple select (4 queries to different tables)
2. Multiple insert (4 queries to different tables)
3. Multiple delete (4 queries to different tables)

Does the JDBC or JDBCTemplate supports that?

EDIT Question:

```
TicketServiceEnforce ticketDao = TicketServiceEnforceImpl.Factory.getInstance();

        // ================================ SELECT ================================
        if (unknownTicketId > ZERO) {
            unknownTicketList = ticketDao.selectUnknownTicket(unknownTicketId);
            if (!unknownTicketList.isEmpty()) {
                attachmentList = ticketDao.selectAttachment(QueryString.SELECT_UNKNOWN_TICKET_ATTACHMENT_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
                ticketCodeList = ticketDao.selectTicketCode(QueryString.SELECT_UNKNOWN_TICKET_CODE_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
                ticketCommentList = ticketDao.selectComment(QueryString.SELECT_UNKNOWN_TICKET_COMMENT_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
            }
        }
        // ================================ INSERT ================================
        // Retrieve customer_id
        if (!unknownTicketList.isEmpty()) {
            // Just display all customers's name in UI
            customerId = ticketDao.selectCustomerIdByName(genericTicket.getCustomerName());

            genericTicket.setCustomerId(customerId);
            genericTicket.setSubject(unknownTicketList.get(ZERO).getSubject());
            genericTicket.setDetails(unknownTicketList.get(ZERO).getDetails());
            genericTicket.setCreationDate(unknownTicketList.get(ZERO).getCreationDate());

            // =====================================================================
            ticketId = ticketDao.createTicket(genericTicket);
            if (ticketId > ZERO) {

                if (!attachmentList.isEmpty()) {
                    ticketDao.createTicketAttachment(ticketId, attachmentList);
                }

                /*
                 * Insert new ticket code
                */
                newTicketCode = generateTicketCode(ticketId);
                if (!ticketCodeList.isEmpty()) {
                    oldTicketCode = ticketCodeList.get(ZERO);

                    ticketDao.createTicketCode(ticketId, newTicketCode);
                }

                /* Insert old unknown ticket code into ticket_email_mapping
                 * This table used to identify the parent child ticket from email - unknown_ticket
                 * by using two queries
                 * 
                 * 1. Select ticket code - select ticket code from ticket_email_mapping using id  
                 * 2. Select ticket id that has previous ticket code - Select id from ticket_email_mapping tem where tem. 
                 * 
                 */
                if (oldTicketCode != null) {
                    String from_sender = null;
                    if (unknownTicketList.size() > ZERO) {
                        from_sender = unknownTicketList.get(ZERO).getFrom();
                    }

                    ticketDao.createTicketEmailMapping(ticketId, oldTicketCode, from_sender);
                }

                if (!ticketCommentList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (GenericTicketComment comment : ticketCommentList) {
                        comment.setTicketId(ticketId);
                    }

                    ticketDao.createTicketComment(QueryString.INSERT_TICKET_COMMENT.toString(), ticketCommentList);
                }

                if (genericTicket.getAssigneeName() != null) {
                    int assigneeId = -1;
                    String firstName = "";
                    TicketAssignee assignee = new TicketAssignee();

                    firstName = genericTicket.getAssigneeName();
                    assigneeId = ticketDao.selectUserId(firstName);

                    assignee.setTicketId(ticketId);
                    assignee.setAssigneeId(assigneeId);

                    ticketDao.createTicketAssignee(assignee);
                }

                // If all successfull
                ticketCreationSuccessful = true;
            }
        }

        // ================================ DELETE ================================
        if (ticketCreationSuccessful) {
            if (!attachmentList.isEmpty()) {
                affectedRow = ticketDao.removeUnknownTicket(QueryString.DELETE_UNKNOWN_TICKET_ATTACHMENT_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
            }

            if (!ticketCommentList.isEmpty()) {
                affectedRow = ticketDao.removeUnknownTicket(QueryString.DELETE_UNKNOWN_TICKET_COMMENT_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
            }

            affectedRow = ticketDao.removeUnknownTicket(QueryString.DELETE_UNKNOWN_TICKET_CODE_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
            affectedRow = ticketDao.removeUnknownTicket(QueryString.DELETE_UNKNOWN_TICKET_BY_ID.toString(), unknownTicketId);
        }
```

This is the DAO using normal query operation. Is it possible to rewrite it in store procedure or bulk operation.

Thanks. Please help.

Comment: Anyone has idea how to do it?

Comment: The jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate is only valid for multiple statements on same sql operation such as insert only.

Answer (score 2):

As the name says `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` you cannot do select in the batch operations. If you want to do all the operation in one go, just create one big SQL achieving your logic and use `JdbcTemplate.#execute(java.lang.String)` method.

Comment: JdbcTemplate.#execute(java.lang.String) does not offer placeholder binding. I need a method which used to execute different sql operation such as select, insert, delete in one go with placeholder binding. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.#execute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#execute%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCallback%29)